# React - Animate first new element in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to animate the first object in an array.

As an example I have this array in my state.

```
this.state = {
    elements: []
}
```

I first populate the array via a post request, so that will look something like this:

```
await this.httpService.getWithAuthorization<Array<BoardElementViewModel>>(`/boards/${this.props.activeBoardState.boardId}/elements`)
                      .then((response: Array<BoardElementViewModel>) => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                elements: response
            }));
        })
        .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
```

At this point nothing should have been animated.

I render this array like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="board-elements">
            {this.props.activeBoardState.boardElements.map((element: BoardElementViewModel, index) => {
                return (
                    <BoardElement
                        key={index}
                        element={element}/>
                    )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

We should have a list of elements now, what I now want to do is add a new element to the top of the list. So I add a new element to the array by using unshift like so:

```
const response = {} //getting response left out of example.

let elements = this.state.elements;
elements.unshift(response);

this.setState(() => ({
    elements: elements 
}));
```

The element will now be `0` in the array and is on top of the list. However, when I now try to animate the "new" element, the animation will be applied to the last element. This is because that is the element what just mounted, the other elements are just being replaced, thus nothing happened to them.

Take a look at this GIF: https://gyazo.com/7d19ba9be962f3d475e59fc8e474da30

Ignore the loading thing, but that illustrates well what I want to achieve.

How can I do this in React?

**Note:** I know how to animate an element, animating the last element in the array is easy, I just need to know how to animate the first one.

Comment: How are you animating the elements?